# Which unicode characters can be used in python3 scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

Some unicode characters can be used to name variables, functions, etc. without any problems, e.g. α.

```
>>> α = "Hello world!"
>>> print(α)
Hello world!
```

Other unicode characters raise an error, e.g. ∇.

```
>>> ∇ = "Hello world"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ∇
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '∇' (U+2207)
```

Which unicode characters can be used to form valid expressions in python? Which unicode characters will raise a SyntaxError?

And, is there a reasonable means of including unicode characters that raise errors in python scripts? I would like to use ∇ in function names that compute gradients, e.g. ∇f to represent the gradient of f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers says:

> Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.

> Python 3.0 introduces additional characters from outside the ASCII range (see [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131)). For these characters, the classification uses the version of the Unicode Character Database as included in the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) module.

Let's check your specific characters:

```
~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category('α')
'Ll'
>>> unicodedata.category('∇')
'Sm'
>>>
```

α is categorized as "Letter, lower-case", while ∇ is a "symbol, math". The former category is allowed in identifiers, but the latter is not. The full list of allowed character categories is available in the docs link at the top.